# Custom screenshots while submitting app to appstore

Tags: ios, screenshot

I want to know whether I can upload custom screenshots of my app while submitting the app to appstore. e.g. Instead of uploading standard screenshots, I want to edit them (add some marketting text, explain screen in the screenshot itself). Will my app get rejected if I submit these custom screenshots?

Comment: Yes you can upload custom screenshots. No they won't be rejected. There are multiple examples of this on the App Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes You can add them. Many apps do it. Check screen shots of Flipboard app. They have description text at the bottom of every screen shot

Answer (score 0):

This scenario app won't be rejected in app store.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can, just concern about image resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will not reject your app if you use their devices like a mockups showing how your app look on device. (I asked this on WWDC) But they will reject if you just put a macbook somewhere on screenshot just to beautify your image.

Creating them can be a tricky part unless you are Photoshop expert. The easiest way is to use tools like https://davinciapps.com